# Find constants of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have the equation

$y'' + 16y' + 64y = 0$

Repeated root of aux eqn $r = -8$

Given the initial conditions, how do I solve for the constants $A$ and $B$?

```
y[t] = (A + Bt) e^(-5 t)
y[0] = 1
y'[0] = 0
```

Comment: `DSolve[y''[t]+16y'[t]+64==0&&y[0]==1&&y'[0]==0,y,t]` or `Solve[y'[0]==0&&y[0]==1/.{y->((A+B#)Exp[-5#]&)}]`

Comment: Also, the general solution is $A-4t+Be^{-16t}$, unless you meant $\ddot y+16\dot y+64 \boxed{y}=0$, in which case it's $(A+Bt)e^{-\boxed{8}t}$

Comment: @2012rcampion fixed! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion here. There is no need to know the DE. You have one equation with 2 unknowns, and so need 2 equations to solve for these 2 unknowns `a,b`

```
Clear[y, t, a, b]
y[t_] := (a + b t) Exp[-5 t];
eq1 = y[0] == 1;
eq2 = (D[y[t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0;
Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As mentioned in the comment, the solution to the ODE you show does not match what you have below it. But the ODE itself is not needed.  You just need 2 equations to solve for 2 unknowns.